# how to use imacros to scrape image url

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

I'm playing with `imacross` to scrape website content, but I'm stuck trying to scrape image URLs from markdown like the following.

```html
<div class="dpimages-icons-box">
   <a href="http://host1.com/1.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9558" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9558.jpg" alt="9558" title="9558"  width="80" height="54" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/2.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9559" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9559.jpg" alt="9559" title="9559"  width="80" height="67" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/3.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9560" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9560.jpg" alt="9560" title="9560"  width="78" height="80" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/4.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9561" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9561.jpg" alt="9561" title="9561"  width="53" height="80" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/5.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9562" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9562.jpg" alt="9562" title="9562"  width="52" height="80" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/6.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9562" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9562.jpg" alt="9562" title="9562"  width="52" height="80" /></a>
   <a href="http://host1.com/7.jpg" class="lightbox" title="9562" rel="dpimages"><img src="//host2.com/9562.jpg" alt="9562" title="9562"  width="52" height="80" /></a>
   <div class="clearing"></div>
  </div>
```

How can I extract the URLs of the first `n` images like:

```
http://host1.com/1.jpg
http://host1.com/2.jpg
http://host1.com/3.jpg
http://host1.com/4.jpg
http://host1.com/5.jpg
```

with `imacros` and save to a `.csv` file?

Comment: Please include the code of your current attempt.

Comment: i was use
`TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:dpimages-icons-box EXTRACT=HTM
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\Scrape\ FILE=pic.csv `
to extract exact hml tag which need extra work to clean the code

Comment: Language and source code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the following macro:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lightbox&&REL:dpimages EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lightbox&&REL:dpimages EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lightbox&&REL:dpimages EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=4 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lightbox&&REL:dpimages EXTRACT=HREF
TAG POS=5 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:lightbox&&REL:dpimages EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\Scrape\ FILE=pic.csv
```